# Parsing a CSV file into Javascript array has one of the keys in quotes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse a CSV file into a Javascript array but have run into a an issue which I am a little stumped.

Though the rest of the objects are parsed without a quote for the key, one of the Keys is in quotes but when I try Object[key] I get an exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I am able to read all other keys except for "information".

My object looks like this:

```
Object {LGA_NAME: "DANDENONG", Lat: "-37.98862", Long: "145.21805", "Information
": "something crashed
"}
```

The CSV file in question is

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97162408/crashdata.csv

The function which I use to parse the CSV file is

```
    function csvToArray(csvString) {

        // The array we're going to build
        var csvArray = [];
        // Break it into rows to start
        var csvRows = csvString.split(/\n/);

        // Take off the first line to get the headers, then split that into an array
        var csvHeaders = csvRows.shift().split(',');

        // Loop through remaining rows
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < csvRows.length; ++rowIndex) {
            var rowArray = csvRows[rowIndex].split(',');

            // Create a new row object to store our data.
            var rowObject = csvArray[rowIndex] = {};

            // Then iterate through the remaining properties and use the headers as keys
            for (var propIndex = 0; propIndex < rowArray.length; ++propIndex) {
                // Grab the value from the row array we're looping through...
                var propValue = rowArray[propIndex];
                // ...also grab the relevant header (the RegExp in both of these removes quotes)
                var propLabel = csvHeaders[propIndex];

                rowObject[propLabel] = propValue;
            }
        }
        return csvArray;
    }
```

Comment: This feels like a end-of-line (EOL) problem.  Which OS are you running?

Comment: `rowObject[propLabel.trim()]=...` should patch the bad input

Comment: Also, how are you converting the file into a string?

Comment: @dandavis That helped!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error and can read the *Information* property. The property names aren't wrapped in quotes (though it might appear that way in the console). Note also that the header is capitalised: "Information", not "information".

Comment: @RobG dandavis's suggestion fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the way you split the string to get the lines. In *NIX systems, lines are broken with `\n`, but in Windows lines are broken with `\r\n`. Because the CSV file is following the Windows convention and you split the lines using just `\n`, the last key is actually `"Information\r"`.

You can fix this issue by replacing `var csvRows = csvString.split(/\n/);` with `var csvRows = csvString.split(/\n|\r\n/);` this way you are going to be able to parse CSV files that use either line break conventions.

Comment: Both ways work. If there is a `\r` the first `\n` won't match and `\r\n` will be tested.